# Extract first field from a delimited file

Tags: bash, unix, sed, split

I have a file like this where `key[x]` is a number and it can be any number followed by some values and they can also be a number. In my file I have lot of entries.

```
key1:value1,value2
key2:value1,value2,value3,value4
key3:value1,value2,value3
```

I want to make a new file in which all keys will be there separated by new line. Is this possible to do? I know we can use `sed` here but what's the best way to do it in case of reading file as in my case.

```
echo "string1:string2:string3:string4:string5" | sed s/:/\\n/g
```

Comment: `cut -f1 -d: file` would give you the keys.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut` to extract the first field:

```
cut -f1 -d: file > file.keys
```

Or you can use `sed` to remove all characters starting with `:`:

```
sed 's/:.*//' file > file.keys
```

For simple extractions like this, `cut` is much faster, especially with large files.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` solution is missing...

```
$ awk -F: '{print $1 > "keys"; print $2 > "values"}' file
```

will split the file into keys and values files.